# Is the speech after the quotative "like" always non-literal?

Tags: word-usage, quotation-marks, descriptive-grammar

I like to use "like" as a quotative for non-literal speech (and non-literal speech in general), speech that no one has said but might have said if given the opportunity.

This is a useful expressive tool but I'm nervous that other people might think I'm attributing speech to people when they didn't actually say it.

An example:

> I went so see him yesterday and he was like, "why didn't you just do it yourself, loser?"

Is this "speech" always metaphorical?

(I'm quite aware that use of "like" as a quotative is controversial, so comments to this effect in any answers might be superfluous or unnecessary.)

Comment: I don't think you mean 'metaphorical', but instead 'non-literal' or 'non-verbatim'

Comment: Sounds good. I'll update the post accordingly. I didn't really know what word to use for the opposite of literal. But non-literal fits well.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure now. The "speech" might not have been said but implied by the persons actions / behaviour. There might not have even been speech. "non-literal" implies there was actually some speech. Metaphorical isn't the best word though. Opinions?

Comment: Is there actually still controversy about quotative like other than "old fogey's" saying it's awful english?

Comment: @AttRigh I think he's referring to paraphrasing. I'm not sure what the adjective of that is.

Comment: I don't think that the use of 'like' as a quotative has settled down yet into a recognisable pattern.

Comment: If the quotation is insulting, like this one, I would take it as literal quotation; the alternative is that the speaker is defaming him by putting insulting words in his mouth. The use of _like_ would then be quotative, I suppose; it certainly wouldn't be approximative.

Comment: @JohnLawler - The more profanity and colloquialisms used, the less I'm apt to think it's verbatim. E.g., *I asked the boss... he was like 'aw hell no, FTS'.* - I doubt most peoples' bosses swear as much as I do. Adding *all* helps. He was *all like* "Naw. That S ain't popping, dawg."

Comment: Vera Regan has a [TED talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAGgKE82034) on the use of like. And of course, there's an [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1483/) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the quotative 'like' is *necessarily* non-literal but it might be a little strange if the quotes part is actually literal, because then I'd feel you'd be more likely to say:

> "I went so see him yesterday and he **said** "why didn't you just do it yourself, loser?"

*That* would be an attempt at a true quote. 'like' is used more to report a general feeling or paraphrase. The 'quoted' part may well be verbatim, but that is not the point, despite it being labeled 'quotative'.

Given this state of things, it might be more accurate to call this a **reportative** 'like', but you should still call it quotative 'like' because that's how everyone else calls it.

Comment: The concept of the [reportative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reportative) is interesting, I hadn't come across it before. German kind of has this at a grammatical level. You use the [present konjunctive (subjunctive)](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivI.html) for *indirect speech*

Comment: I don’t think your first paragraph holds up here. I’ve heard many a teenage girl use quotative _like_ to report direct speech—for some, to such an extent that it seems to have almost completely ousted the verb _say_ in their vocabulary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I used the word 'necessarily' intentionally. 'like' is like 'said' but I hear it more often as attempting to paraphrase what someone said rather than be verbatim. Hm... maybe 'said' is already like that anyway?

Comment: @Mitch It wasn’t so much the “necessarily” bit, but the “otherwise you’d say” bit that I don’t think holds up. “Otherwise you’d be more likely to hear” would be more accurate, I think. (Actually, I don’t think ‘otherwise’ fits at all here—‘then’ seems more logical. But that’s a different matter.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh OK I get it. I see what you say but... I just feel like no one is -really- quoting anyone, but reporting something slightly reworded.

Comment: If you're going to quote me on it, then you'd better say I said it. +1

Answer (score 7):

In your example you are actually implying that he did say that. When you use "like" like this it's entirely possible for people to think the person actually said it, and it's entirely possible for them to think the person didn't. It's a minefield. 
You could use: "He looked like he was gonna say/he was about to say ..."
Or you could just describe it otherwise like "I went to see him yesterday and he looked pissed".
But if that's too long for you, you could run the original description with the quotative "like" in your mind and see what you're implying.
If it could be taken in both ways and it doesn't do any harm if people got it wrong you can use it, it'd just count as exaggeration.
And a good story's always better than the truth.

Comment: Interesting. I get the impression that "like" differs between different dialects of English.

Comment: Well i'm not a native speaker, so can't answer that for you.

Comment: I don't know. I get the impression non-native speakers pay attention while native speakers just ignore stuff and carry on regardless!

Comment: [This piece](https://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2015/01/25/linguists-are-like-get-used/ruUQoV0XUTLDjx72JojnBI/story.html) says that "In the early 1980s, it was primarily used to report inner states, not direct speech," but now it is an " opening into either direct quotation or inner condition".

Comment: @AttRigh That sounds about right; I'd probably add paraphrasing to the list as well - sometimes it is framed as a direct quote but not worded verbatim, and "like" is occasionally defended as being a disclaimer to that fact (although it certainly doesn't always imply being non-verbatim).

Comment: there's an episode of Seinfeld that talks about this; "did you really say that?", "no".

Comment: *like* 2: informal. used to convey a person's reported attitude or feelings in the form of direct speech (whether or not representing an actual quotation). *so she comes into the room and she's like “Where is everybody?”* – Google. **Where's the definition that says *like* means to imply what was actually said?**

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are accurate in the fact that what is quoted after *like* can be verbatim, but doesn't have to be.

Honestly when I read that sentence, I kind of read it in a “Jersey Girl”, Kardashian-esque tone. That just means that whoever is speaking is either dramatizing the conversation for story purposes or repeating what was ***perceived*** to be said.

Comment: **"dramatizing"** In this example probably: it was chosen for simplicity. It becomes more useful when what you are trying to imply is more subtle / difficult to say directly. The time I use quotative forms most is chatting with people about quite technical things. For example, "I thought this framing said something, but he was all like, 'No entity without identity'" At its best, I think "like" can concisely pack a lot of meaning into a sentence (particularly when used in spoken form). At its worse, you are correct, it can be an exercise in projection!

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but even with the sentence that was provided "...but he was all like, 'No entity without identity'", I read that as bit of a **dramatized** version of what was actually said in order to **emphasize** the importance the quotes. From my experience, the word "like" used in this way is a bit informal, and often used this way in storytelling, whether or not the story is true.

Comment: I agree entirely. I wonder if the informality is a function of the conciseness (based on shared knowledge) rather than the grammatical form itself. I only really use this in technical chat forums :/. Although I might put something like "It's as though we are saying, 'Who cares about truth when there are arguments to win?'" when in something longer form.

Comment: *like* 2: informal. **used to convey a person's reported attitude or feelings in the form of direct speech (whether or not representing an actual quotation).** *so she comes into the room and she's like “Where is everybody?”* – Google.

Comment: @Mazura thanks for the google link. Alas, google (or even dictionary definitions) for new / colloquial speech is not necessarily to be trusted.

Comment: @att -  The accepted  answer is the one that needs to come up with the definition for this new (?) meaning of the word like.